# How to add an additional dependency to a block index.asset.php file

Tags: javascript, block-editor, react

I have a plugin that registers four different Gutenberg blocks. I build them using the `build` script from the `wp-scripts` package. As you all surely know, this script automatically generates an `index.asset.php` file with an array with all the script dependencies for each block. For example:

```
<?php return array('dependencies' => array('react', 'wp-block-editor', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-compose', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-primitives'), 'version' => 'a955a4059265b7ad1ce6');
```

I need to add the `masonry` script (included in WP) to this dependency array in just ONE (not ALL) of the blocks, like this:

```
<?php return array('dependencies' => array('react', 'wp-block-editor', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-compose', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-primitives', 'masonry'), 'version' => 'a955a4059265b7ad1ce6');
```

I know that I can add this dependency manually after I build the blocks, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this automatically via the block `block.json` file, a custom `webpack.config.js` file or anything else.

The contents of the `block.json` file is:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "my/masonry-block",
    "title": "My Masonry Block",
    "description": "Display a Masonry gallery.",
    "textdomain": "my-domain",
    "category": "media",
    "attributes": {
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": []
        },
        "columns": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 1,
            "maximum": 8,
            "default": 3
        },
        "gap": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "10px"
        },
        "captions": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "spacing": {
            "margin": true,
            "padding": true
        },
        "align": [ "center" ]
    },
    "editorScript": [
        "file:./index.js",
        "imagesloaded",
        "masonry"
    ],
    "viewScript": [
        "file:./view.js",
        "imagesloaded",
        "masonry"
    ],
    "style": [
        "file:./style-index.css",
        "file:./view.css"
    ],
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css"
}
```

I'm registering the block with:

```
register_block_type(
    __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/masonry',
    array(
        'render_callback' => array( $this, 'render_block_masonry' ),
    )
);
```

This is the block `edit` function (some code omitted for brevity):

```
const displayItems = (items) => {
    return (
        items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div className="gallery-item" key={index}>
                    <figure>
                        <a data-rel="collection" href={item.url} data-sub-html={item.caption}>
                            <img className={`wp-image-${item.id}`} src={item.url} alt={item.alt} key={item.id} />
                        </a>
                        {captions && item.caption &&
                            <figcaption className="wp-element-caption">
                                {item.caption}
                            </figcaption>
                        }
                    </figure>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
};

const containerMasonryRef = useRefEffect((element) => {
    var msnry;

    const { ownerDocument } = element;
    const { defaultView } = ownerDocument;

    if (!defaultView.imagesLoaded || !defaultView.Masonry) {
        console.log('scripts not loaded');
        return;
    }
    
    imagesLoaded(element, function () {
        console.log('images loaded');
        msnry = new defaultView.Masonry(element, {
            itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            percentPosition: true,
            gutter: parseInt(gap),
        });
    });

    return () => {
        msnry?.destroy();
    }

}, [items, columns, gap, captions]);

const containerLightboxRef = useRefEffect((element) => {
    lightGallery(element, {
        selector: 'a[data-rel^=collection]',
        mode: 'lg-fade',
        preload: 4,
        counter: false,
        download: false,
        youtubePlayerParams: {
            autoplay: 0
        },
        vimeoPlayerParams: {
            autoplay: 0
        }
    });

    return () => {
        window?.lgData[element?.getAttribute('lg-uid')]?.destroy(true);
    }

}, []);

const mergedRefs = useMergeRefs([
    containerMasonryRef,
    containerLightboxRef,
]);

return (
    <>
        <InspectorControls>
            <PanelBody
                title={__('Settings')}
            >
                <RangeControl
                    label={__('Columns')}
                    value={columns}
                    onChange={setColumns}
                    min={1}
                    max={8}
                />
                <UnitControl
                    label={__('Gap between items')}
                    min="0"
                    onChange={setGap}
                    value={gap}
                    units={units}
                />
            </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>
        <BlockControls group="block">
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={toggleCaptions}
                icon={captionIcon}
                isPressed={captions}
                label={
                    captions
                        ? __('Hide captions')
                        : __('Show captions')
                }
            />
        </BlockControls>
        <BlockControls group="other">
            {items.length > 0 && (
                <ToolbarGroup>
                    <MediaUploadCheck>
                        <MediaUpload
                            allowedTypes={['image']}
                            multiple={true}
                            gallery={true}
                            value={items.map((item) => item.id)}
                            onSelect={setItems}
                            render={({ open }) => (
                                <ToolbarButton onClick={open}>
                                    {__('Edit items')}
                                </ToolbarButton>)}
                        />
                    </MediaUploadCheck>
                </ToolbarGroup>
            )}
        </BlockControls>
        <MediaUploadCheck>
            {items.length > 0 ?
                <div {...blockProps}>
                    <div className="gallery-items" style={{ '--gap': gap }} ref={mergedRefs}>
                        <div className="grid-sizer"></div>
                        {displayItems(items)}
                    </div>
                </div>
                :
                <MediaPlaceholder
                    accept="image/*"
                    allowedTypes={['image']}
                    onSelect={setItems}
                    multiple={true}
                    gallery={true}
                    addToGallery={true}
                    handleUpload={true}
                    labels={
                        { title: __('My Masonry Block') }
                    }
                />
            }
        </MediaUploadCheck>
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you do not need to worry about adding the Masonry's script handle *to the `dependencies` array in the asset file* (`index.asset.php`).

All you needed to do to make your Masonry code work properly is by using the [`script` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#script) to add the `masonry` (and `imagesloaded`) as dependencies for your editor and view/front-end scripts.

```json
"editorScript": "file:./index.js",
"script": [
    "imagesloaded",
    "masonry"
],
"viewScript": "file:./view.js",
```

<strike>I don't know and haven't checked further why adding `masonry` to the `editorScript` *and* `viewScript` did not work, but</strike> the above (trick) worked well for me.

- Using the `script` property to add the dependency, is also the reason why the *Gutenberg Test Iframed Masonry Block* worked. I.e. The plugin [manually registered](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/4bf1d217f631af93031862989703122f2f474545/packages/e2e-tests/plugins/iframed-masonry-block.php#L25-L30) the shared editor and front-end script, and the plugin also [sets `"script": "iframed-masonry-block-script"` in the block metadata](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/4bf1d217f631af93031862989703122f2f474545/packages/e2e-tests/plugins/iframed-masonry-block/block.json#L16).

---

For completeness though, I created a simple Webpack plugin which basically modifies the asset source before it is written to the asset file, but (hopefully) after the [Dependency Extraction Webpack Plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin/) added the asset to the compilation queue.

[Here's the plugin](https://gist.github.com/5ally/df2ab8c8509853356ed26b55d8202927#file-dependency-modification-webpack-plugin-js) which I placed it in the root project folder.

And [here's my custom Webpack config file](https://gist.github.com/5ally/df2ab8c8509853356ed26b55d8202927#file-webpack-config-js), i.e. `webpack.config.js`.

BTW, thanks for sharing about the Gutenberg Test Iframed Masonry Block.  Happy coding!

---

**Update 21 Feb 2024**

Regarding the strikethrough text above:

- Scripts (and styles) in the editor canvas are enqueued via [`_wp_get_iframed_editor_assets()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_get_iframed_editor_assets/) which runs `add_filter( 'should_load_block_editor_scripts_and_styles', '__return_false' )` and then `do_action( 'enqueue_block_assets' )`. [( see source on GitHub )](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/block-editor.php#L335-L341)
- [`wp_enqueue_registered_block_scripts_and_styles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_registered_block_scripts_and_styles/) is then called because it is hooked on the [`enqueue_block_assets` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_assets/).
- So the reason why Masonry was not loaded in the editor canvas is because the above function will only enqueue *editor* assets if [`wp_should_load_block_editor_scripts_and_styles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_should_load_block_editor_scripts_and_styles/) (which applies the above filter) returns true.

  That is understandable, though. However, that function also *never* enqueues the **view/front-end-*only*** scripts!

  More specifically, if you look at the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2613-L2646), the function should have also enqueued the scripts in the [`view_script_handles` property](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/class-wp-block-type.php#L204-L210), i.e. `$block_type->view_script_handles`.

  I have no idea why are they not being enqueued?  Perhaps, as you commented, "*This might be a bug because it makes no sense*"..

Comment: I posted the contents of my `block.json` file. The `masonry` script handle is already in there.

Comment: I added the block register code to my original question. The block is loading but the Masonry script is not because it's not added to the dependencies array in the `index.asset.php` file.

Comment: Lol, sorry, I've deleted my previous comments. I forgot Masonry is part of WordPress  Nonetheless, regarding this - "*it's not added to the dependencies array in the `index.asset.php file`*" - yes, that isn't what adding the `masonry` to `block.json` does. But, `masonry` will be recognized as a dependency for your script and therefore, *should* be loaded when your block is loaded.

Comment: So, are you absolutely sure the Masonry script is not being loaded?  How did you confirm/check that?

Comment: Sorry, I've checked the source code and it seems that the Masonry script is loaded BUT, outside of the iFramed template editor in Gutenberg. I based my code in the following example: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/c7ff22ae513ecc0cdc0bda9c9fffedd53b2aee9b/packages/e2e-tests/plugins/iframed-masonry-block/editor.js According to a core developer, this is the way to load the Masonry script INSIDE the iFramed editor, but it's not working in my case.

Comment: Yes, `Masonry` is within the parent window, but did your code actually work when you manually added `masonry` to the dependencies array? What's your full `edit` function?

Comment: I added my `edit` function (some code omitted for brevity). As you can see I'm loading both Masonry and a Lightbox script called lightGallery. The latter is working with no problems (Apparently, it doesn't need to be loaded inside the iFrame to work).

Comment: I believe it does need to be loaded inside the iFrame. But anyway, see the revised answer.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I apologize for taking so long to respond to your reply. Right now, I'm leaning towards your option 3. But I'm seeing that when a script handle is used in the `editorScript` or `script` fields in `block.json`, `wp-scripts build` doesn't build the related files to the block (*.js, *.css and *.asset.php) in the `build` folder. Is this the expected behavior? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: That behavior didn't happen in my case, so maybe you're just missing a `"main": "build/index.js"` in your `package.json` file? Nonetheless, please see the revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for your revised answer. Adding masonry and imagesloaded to the `script` prop instead of `editorScript` makes the whole thing work as expected, and both scripts are now loaded INSIDE the iframe. It's puzzling why this happens. I remember something similar happening with another block I was working on months ago, where a script needed to be loaded in the `script` prop to make it work in the editor. This might be a bug on the Gutenberg side because it makes no sense.

Comment: I revised my answer, yes, again! Also, I +1 your question because maybe you're right about that being a bug in WordPress/Gutenberg core. But if it wasn't, then this is truly puzzling!